# how to use showlabels package in IEEEtran class

Tags: labels

I need to show the labels of the equation, besides equation number, in my `.pdf` file in the `IEEEtran` class.

For that I use the [\usepackage[right]{showlabels}](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/showlabels/showlabels.pdf). But I am unable to show the labels. For instance my code is

```
%http://elevatorlady.ca/doc/refcard/expressions.html

\documentclass[11pt,final,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[right]{showlabels}


\ifCLASSINFOpdf 
\else
\fi
\hyphenation{}


\begin{document}

\title{Example}

\begin{abstract}
%\boldmath
This work is summarizing ............

\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle


\section{Introduction}

 This is the introduction...........

\hfill 

\section{My section}  

We have a system

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
\vec{z}=\vec{b}s+\vec{w} \label{a30} \IEEEyesnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Any idea please.

Comment: Please edit your document to make it compilable

Comment: If `final` option is used, then no labels are shown, but this is not the cause of your problem. Remove it anyway, please

Comment: If instead of `IEEEeqnarray` a regular `equation` is used, it works.

Comment: @Ignasi: Yes, `IEEEeqnarray` is a weird beast ;-)

Comment: The `showkeys` package works (but it doesn't print the label in the margin, with `IEEEeqnarray`). On the other hand, why not simply using `align`?

Comment: @Ignasi Yes it works now with regular equation. thanks

Comment: Your usage of eqnarray seems to be missing `&` either side of the `=`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: the `&` characters where there in the original version but the OP decided to post a (completely) different version

Answer (score 1):

Based on the useful comments by egreg, Christian Hupfer, Ignasi. I finally figured out a way to show labels of the equations, in the IEEEtran class, in a output .pdf file.

1) Change the **final** in \documentclass[11pt,**final**,onecolumn]{IEEEtran} to **draftcls** ,

2) use **\usepackage{showkeys}** instead of **\usepackage{showlabels}**.

Done.